# Jade - Angular 2 Structural Directives in Jade

Tags: html, angularjs, angular, pug, angular2-directives

I'm trying to learn to use Angular 2 while creating templates using Jade and importing the transpiled .html files.

How can I include *ngIf and *ngFor in Jade?

Trying to achieve the following in HTML:

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="products && products.length">
```

I'm trying the following in Jade:

```
div.container(*ngIf='products && products.length')
```

The above code doesn't work! Help?

Answer (score 0):

```
template([ngIf]='products && products.length')
```

or

```
div.container([hidden]='!(products && products.length)')
```

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be useful to lift your content quality up

Answer (score 0):

Try somethink like this:
[image]

How you include support pug (jade)?

In every *.ts file try somethin like: **'require!pug-loader()myfile.component.pug'**

or create custom webpack file? (and now didn't use angular-cli)

or use pre-compilers that create *.html file around pug

or do [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48556518/install-use-pug-jade-with-angular-cli-for-angular-2-no-custom-webpack)?

Comment: also u can do this: p([class.hidden]='any_condition', [class.show]='condition')