# How to insert raw Pug code in HTML file (external file or inside the HTML file)

Tags: html, angularjs, pug

I want to put some multiline Pug into an HTML file but I can't find info on how to do this. I am using Angular and also new to programming.

```
var cards = [{ title: 'Mountain View', copy: 'Check out all of these gorgeous mountain trips with beautiful views of, you guessed it, the mountains', button: 'View Trips' }, { title: 'To The Beach', copy: 'Plan your next beach trip with these fabulous destinations', button: 'View Trips' }, { title: 'Desert Destinations', copy: 'It\'s the desert you\'ve always dreamed of', button: 'Book Now' }, { title: 'Explore The Galaxy', copy: 'Seriously, straight up, just blast off into outer space today', button: 'Book Now' }]

mixin card(title, copy, button)
  .card
    .content
      h2.title= title
      p.copy= copy
      button.btn= button

main.page-content
  each card in cards
    +card(card.title, card.copy, card.button)
```

Comment: Do you want to display the Pug code, or do you want to compile the Pug into HTML and then include the HTML in your file?

Comment: I want to compile the Pug into HTML and then include it my main  the HTML file

Comment: Would recommend searching about how to compile pug in an angular project. This seems like it might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48556518/pug-support-for-angular-2-angular-4-angular-6-angular-cli-angular-cli-6/48556519#48556519